# xquery to check xquery how to check if value of boolean variable is true

Tags: if-statement, boolean, xquery

I am writing a xquery in which I have to check if the value of an attribute is true. The attribute / element is defined as Boolean.
I tried multiple options but I am not able to get the correct value, the logic works for other elements but not for 'MainCustomer' since it is defined Boolean. How can I write the xquery for this?

Below is the example of my request:

```
<Maintenance xmlns="*******">
<AccountPersons>
  <APH AccountID="56987" LastFinancialRespSwitch="Y" LastMainCustomerSwitch="Y" LastPersonID="987569" QuickAddSwitch="false"/>
  <APR AccountID="98759" AccountRelationshipType="MIN" BillAddressSource="PER" PersonID="000000" MainCustomer="true"></APR>
  <APR AccountID="123456" AccountRelationshipType="MAIN" BillAddressSource="PERSON" PersonID="123456" MainCustomer="false"></APR>
</AccountPersons>
</Maintenance>
```

I am using the `if` statement inside for loop.APR is an array. 
I want to get the value of BillAddressSource from only those APR where MainCustomer="true" 
below xquery doesn't work it gives me the values from all the APR.

```
 if (fn:boolean($MaintenanceResponse/ns1:AccountPersons/ns1:APR[$position]/@MainCustomer))
    then
       <acc:data>      
               {if ($MaintenanceResponse/ns1:AccountPersons/ns1:APR[$position]/@BillAddressSource)
                then <acc:addressSource>{fn:data($MaintenanceResponse/ns1:AccountPersons/ns1:APR[$position]/@BillAddressSource)}</acc:addressSource>
                else ()
            }
       </acc:data>
```

Another xquery I tried is, this gives me syntax error

```
        if ($MaintenanceResponse/ns1:AccountPersons/ns1:APR[$position]/@MainCustomer='true')
    then
       <acc:data>      
               {if ($MaintenanceResponse/ns1:AccountPersons/ns1:APR[$position]/@BillAddressSource)
                then <acc:addressSource>{fn:data($MaintenanceResponse/ns1:AccountPersons/ns1:APR[$position]/@BillAddressSource)}</acc:addressSource>
                else ()
            }
       </acc:data>
```

Please help me find a correct if statement. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it depends a little on whether your query/processor is schema-aware. (Is there an "import schema" declaration?)

The effective boolean value of an attribute is true if the attribute exists, regardless of its value, and regardless whether the data is schema-validated. Both `if (@married) ...` and `if (boolean(@married)) ...` test the effective boolean value.

If you want to test that the attribute exists and has the value 'true' or '1', use a cast: `if (xs:boolean(@married)) ...`. This will work whether or not the data is typed (by schema validation). Note the distinction between the `boolean()` function (sometimes written `fn:boolean()`), which gets the effective boolean value, and the `xs:boolean()` cast or constructor function, which does a data conversion.

If the data is untyped, you can use `if (@married = 'true')`, but this will fail with a type error if the data is typed as boolean. Also, it doesn't test for all legitimate boolean values (" true ", "1", " 1", etc).

If you know that the data has been typed by schema validation, you can use any of the following:

- `if (data(@married)) ...` but there's no real reason to prefer this.
- `if (@married = true())` - the expression `@married = true()` returns true if the attribute exists and is true, false if it doesn't exist or is false
- `if (@married eq true())` - the expression `@married eq true()` returns true if the attribute exists and is true, false if it exists and is false, `()` (empty sequence) if the attribute doesn't exist; the effect of returning `()` in the context of `if()` is the same as returning false. Using "eq" rather than "=" could give a tiny performance benefit.

If you're testing for false (again assuming typed data), the distinction between `@married = false()` and `@married eq false()` and `@married != true()` and `not(@married = true())` is more subtle. If `@married` doesn't exist, then any comparison using `=`, `eq`, `!=`, `ne` is effectively false regardless whether the other operand is `true()` or `false()`. So `not(@married = true())` doesn't mean the same as `(@married != true())`, nor does it mean the same as `(@married = false())`.

I could go on for pages about this. In my book (XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference) I do just that (see pages 581 to 592).

Comment: Thanks michael. Yes i have import declarations. I haven’t mentioned the complete xquery. I have to test the 2 nd condition tht you mentioned. Which is check if the attribute exists and if its value is true. Will xs:boolean(@married) the correct answer.It should not hv any other value other than true. I tried if(@married=‘true’) that gave validation error.

Comment: If you know that it's typed, you can also test `if (@married = true())` or `if (@married eq true())` - I'll add those options to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. Both of these options worked. xs:boolen(@married), if(@married=true())

Comment: How can I use this in an return statement?

Comment: @chovy Don't ask supplementary questions as a comment on an answer to different question. Raise a new question and give full details of what you are trying to achieve and where you are getting stuck. You can always cross-reference this question/answer if relevant.